# Pythonic solution for writing management commands

Tags: python, django, django-models, cron

I am using django 1.3 and python 2.7.

**CLIENT REQUIREMENT :**

I have a client requirement which says that an email against a user activity should be generated to the user based on his/her preference. These preferences are based on time, therefore, can be daily, weekly or monthly.

The preferences are multi-selectable, meaning that one user can receive for example daily as well as weekly notifications.

**MODELS.PY :**

```
class Preference(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Notification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    preferences = models.ManyToManyField(Preference)
```

Class Preference contains only the time preference i.e daily, weekly, monthly

Class Notification would keep the specific users preference. The management command would use this table to send emails to the user.

**QUESTION :**

I have some doubts while writing a management command.

1. Should I write only one command that would handle all 3 or more cases or 1 command per case?
2. Should I add any further information to the preference models. For example the number of hours after which the daily mail should be sent?
3. Is the cron responsible to run the command according to the time preference?
4. What is the most pythonic way to solve this problem (if any one wants to suggest)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since you have predefined intervals, (daily, weekly, monthly), you can just have one command that handles everything.
2. You might want to include a field which keeps track of when the last email was sent out, which is updated every time email is sent out for the user.
3. No, cron is like a polling system - executes a piece of code if certain conditions are valid. However, the developer can define when and how frequently the cron executes
4. I would implement it as a straight forward management command for simplicity. If it is really complex, consider using django-celery (I would rather keep it simple)

One more thing you can do is add options to Management command which gives more control over things like - run command for only `preference_type=daily` or for specific user, etc if you want more flexibility.

Comment: So basically you agree with the thought process? I am heading in the right direction?

Comment: Yes I do also want to ignore django-celery and rabbitMQ.

Answer (score 1):

1. I would create one command (as entry point) because it is easier to register in cron
2. Yes, Keeping last sent email will be nothing but beneficial, keeping the time that the preference was added might be beneficial too, django provides `auto_now_add` for this purpose.  Any information that could help yourself down the road, or provide more information about the users action
3. Cron will be registered to run in certain intervals, it can be the "entry point" to your management command.  It will just call the management command for a certain user, every X minutes. The management commmand should implement the logic involved with determining if an email has already been sent or not
4. Management command, with well structured/thought out internal functions

Comment: Karthikr and your answers were almost the same, but he replied first, therefore, I have accepted his answer, though up-voted both. Thanx :)